Move a Outlook calendar module Navigation folder from one group to anotheri
I am trying to move the navigation folder to new navigation group which I am creating. But I am running into "You don't have appropriate permission to perform this operation". What am I missing here.. can anybody guide
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application = Globals.OutlookAddin.Application
Dim calendarModule As Outlook.CalendarModule = outlookApp.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(Outlook.OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleCalendar)
Dim calendarGroups As Outlook.NavigationGroups = calendarModule.NavigationGroups

Dim newGroup As Outlook.NavigationGroup = calendarGroups.Create("TestGroup")
Dim MAPIspace As Outlook.NameSpace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim sourceGroup As Outlook.NavigationGroup 
Dim navFolder As NavigationFolder  

For Each CalGrp As Outlook.NavigationGroup In calendarModule.NavigationGroups
    If CalGrp.Name = "TEST MAX" Then
        sourceGroup = CalGrp
    End If
Next

For Each CalFldr As Outlook.NavigationFolder In sourceGroup.NavigationFolders
    newGroup.NavigationFolders.Add(CalFldr.Folder)
Next


